# Watchr and inotify

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing

So, I've using autotest so far and I've set it up to use autotest-inotify. I've been wondering, is there inotify support for watchr?

Answer (score 0):

arrrrgggghhhh. The answer was under my nose. https://github.com/mynyml/watchr Under Install section

If you're on Linux/BSD and have the rev gem installed, Watchr will detect it and use it automatically. This will make Watchr evented.

According to the gem specification:
"summary: Rev is a Ruby binding to the libev high performance event library"

so the libev library needs to be installed.